# Script only extraction one five of five

Tags: r

I have a Directory with 10 NCDF4 files.  I wrote a script to separate out the file with greater than a 100 observations in the file observations dimension. I want to write to a text file, the files meeting that  criteria. But when I run the script, only the last one of the five that meets the criteria is written to the text file. I should have 5 files. What am I doing wrong
My script is below:

```
x <- filenames <- list.files("D:/Rwork/Test", pattern = "*.nc", full.names = TRUE)
file.create("stationstouse.data")
for (i in x) {
    filetoopen <- (i)
    a <- nc_open(filetoopen)
    D <- a$dim$obs$vals
    z <- length(D) 
    if (z > 100) {  
        fileConn <- file("stationstouse.data") 
        write("\n",file = fileConn, append = TRUE)
        write(fileConn, file = fileConn, append = TRUE) 
        close(fileConn)
        print(i)
    }
    nc_close(a)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try opening the file in "append" mode:

```
fileConn <- file("stationstouse.data", "a")
```

Comment: Tried That  Unfortunately no sucess

Comment: Is length the right test function? Perhaps ' nrow'?

Comment: Let me try, no luck

Comment: I think it is something to do whit

Comment: I think it is something to do with -   write(fileConn, file = fileConn, append = TRUE)  part of the script. But I have no idea  how

Comment: Is the data you are using publically available? What is the output of `names(a$dim)`? Also, you have a `print()` statement in the for-loop -- are you seeing that called five times as you expect? This would at least confirm that the for-loop condition is being met.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, `write` is a wrapper to `cat`, and according to the documentation for `cat`:

> append logical. Only used if the argument file is the name of file (and not a connection or "|cmd"). If TRUE output will be appended to file; otherwise, it will overwrite the contents of file.

Therefore, replace:

```
write("\n",file = fileConn, append = TRUE)
write(fileConn, file = fileConn, append = TRUE)
```

with

```
write("\n",file = "stationstouse.data", append = TRUE)
write(i, file = "stationstouse.data", append = TRUE)
```

and you should get at least more than one line of output.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Let me try it give me a min

Comment: Good try but instead of getting the last file I got a line of 3 in the txt file ??

Comment: @ian: I was meaning to ask why you are writing out the `fileConn` to "stationstouse.data". That is the `3` that you are seeing? See if my edit is an improvement.

Comment: Hi Aichao,  No error -Error in cat(x, file = file, sep = c(rep.int(sep, ncolumns - 1), "\n"),  : 
  argument "x" is missing, with no default

Comment: @ian: that happens when `write` has no data (i.e., the `i`) to write. Are you sure you edited your code with respect to the answer?

Comment: Aichao . It worked Thank you so much. Wish i could buy you a pint